# datagridview delete row using adapter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Ini my application for create/update/delete am using `arapter.Update(Dataset)`. Everything working fine but am looking how to add dialog box for question before `update` is executed

When i click on remove button i want to see dialog box for question like this:

```
 DialogResult delete = MessageBox.Show("are you sure you want to delete this ?", "Delete Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

if (delete == DialogResult.OK)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Deleted");
  }
```

This code i want to put in this code below but am not shure how determine if is delete command triggered!

```
  private void saveToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.bs.EndEdit();

            cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

            dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = cmb.GetUpdateCommand();           
            dataAdapter.Update(this.ds, "grupe");

            MessageBox.Show("Update successful");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The update method returns an int indicating how many rows were affected: `rows = dataAdapter.Update(...)`.  DataAdapters are very powerful though and the count could include Inserted and Updated rows as well.

Comment: so if return 1 how can i determine does user click remove or update

Comment: You can find [changed rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thc1eetk.aspx) which are going to be deleted, edited or inserted using your `DataTable` before you call `Update` method of `SqlDataAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Write a method which has `DataRowState` as parameter;

```
 public DialogResult Dialog(DataRowState state)
        {

            if (state == DataRowState.Modified)
            {

                DialogResult update = MessageBox.Show("are you sure you want to update this ?", "Update Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

                return update;
            }
            if (state == DataRowState.Deleted)
            {

                DialogResult delete = MessageBox.Show("are you sure you want to delete this ?", "Delete Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

                return delete;
            }
            return DialogResult.None;

        }
```

And at button click;

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataTable dt = dataTbl.GetChanges(); //it will return the changes
            foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (Dialog(item.RowState) == DialogResult.OK) 
                {
                    SqlCommandBuilder cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adp);
                    adp.UpdateCommand = cmb.GetUpdateCommand();
                    adp.Update(this.dataTbl);

                }
            }
        }
```

`DataTable` can be null always. Use `datatable.AcceptChanges()` after filling adapter.

Hope helps,